# Write a script to obtain the date of the last month

Tags: bash, scripting, date, last

I would like to obtain the date of the previous month as output and store it in a variable using a bash script.

For example, if today's date is 07/04/2023, I would like the output to be 06/04/2023.

Comment: What do you want to do with the previous month that does not have a matching day, such as 03/31/2023 ->  <s>02/31/2023</s>?

Comment: And what part are you having trouble with?

Comment: I want to use particular date (may be last month , 4 months back, 6 months etc) in script which will be used to run and generate reports . how to get such date using bashscript

Comment: Welcome to the site. When asked for clarifications, please don't respond in comments, but edit your post to include the requested information. Reading through the comments is rather painful, and comments are subject to removal without notice by moderators. Also, please add any approaches you have already tried, including where it failed, so that contributors don't post answers that you already know won't work.

Comment: In python, I change to first of the month and subtract one day. But in January I had a issue, and had to add extra logic to also change to December of previous year. Python has modules for date and date math, bash does not have much, but has lots of formatting tools. see`man date`

Answer (score 1):

GNU `date` supports specifying a date in "natural language".

```
$ date -d "a month ago"
Sun Jun  4 02:58:08 PM CEST 2023
$ date -d "2 days ago 3 months ago"
Sun Apr  2 01:59:00 PM CEST 2023
```

Use the `+FORMAT` option of `date` do format the result in any way you like.

Comment: The issue is that `date -d '2023-03-31 - 1 month' '+%F'` says `2023-03-03`. It goes back to 2023-02-31 and then normalises the date. Any time you move from a longer month to a shorter one, there is ambiguity to resolve, in the requirement first and then in the solution.